# Problems loading a script into an html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

js, 
i'm trying to build a simple server node that put data taken from an odata.
My problem is that every time that i run the server, the html page will display:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I tryed to apply some solution found on stackoverflow with no result.
somebody can help me ?

---

I was able to create a script for retrive the odata, below the sample script data:

---

**Script.js**

```
var http =  Request("Url",
    (error, response, body) => {
        //some operation
    });
```

This script return a Json. The Json is the data that should be input from the html page, which must construct a table with such data.

---

**Home.html**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">

    var data = bodyglob.data;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
        html += '<tr>';
        var flag = 0;
        $.each(data[0], function (index, value) {
            html += '<th>' + index + '</th>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            html += '<tr>';
            $.each(value, function (index2, value2) {
                html += '<td>' + value2 + '</td>';
            });
            html += '<tr>';
        });
        html += '</table>';
        $('body').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

I will put the **server.js** code below.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const header = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000);
const send = (source, destination, status = 200, headers = header) => {
    destination.writeHead(status, headers);
    fs.createReadStream(source).pipe(destination);
};
app.use( express.static('public'));
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    const url = req.url;

    if (url === '/') {
        return send(__dirname+'/home.html', res);
    }
    else {
        return send(__dirname+'/404.html', res, 404, {});
    }

});

const callback = () => {
    const address = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`
  Server avviato all'indirizzo http://${address}:${port}
  `);
};

server
    .listen(
        8000,
        '127.0.0.1',
        callback
    );
```

Comment: if file is not found you probably have the wrong path. try using an absolute path

Comment: the project tree is like that:
-projectname
--server.js
--home.html
--script.js
I tryied every single combination of path

Comment: which file is not being found?

Comment: script.js i'm colling in the html to retrieve a JSON

Comment: i don't see that.  you load odatafunction.js but i don't see where you load script.js.  also, with odatafunction.js you either use the src or define the function but not both

Comment: is the actual name sorry, i change it to have a generic name, but i didn't change in the html.

Comment: on your server do you have a folder that looks like public_html ? is script.js located there or in public_html/projects/... ?

Comment: Server.js, home.html, script.js are in the same folder